# How to handle infrastructure for the website in PHP which will be used many times?

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, multiple-instances, code-sharing

I have a few PHP Laravel projects (restful API, admin app, client app). There is only one database which is used by API. The project is some kind of app which can be used by some companies. They have access to admin panel, client web page, they can use own API, they can make own users, permissions and so on. There is no problem if this project will be used by one client, but I'm going to sell this app to many people. I will be responsible for updates, hosting, configurations etc. I wonder how to make it the best way and I have a few ideas.

1. I thought about cloning the app on the server each time someone buys it from me. This requires setting up a new subdomain on the server and a lot of disk space. Not sure about it.
2. Or maybe cloning the app and sharing some files with symlinks like vendor, node_modules etc.
3. Another idea is to make it as a one project with many databases for different clients, but how to make it in Laravel in the best way? I will need some dynamic way to change the database connections (I want each client to have separate database), I'm not sure about conflicts with sessions, cache etc.
4. Maybe separate databases is a wrong idea, and it's better to have one database and make it as a one project and sell the access to project? But then I need to keep data of my client in one database.

What do you think?

Comment: Re: #3, something like https://laravel-news.com/laravel-multidomain-package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create this application as SaaS (software as a service). You can give them some default templates of front end or even client app (website and admin part), but keep all backend at your servers. Make REST endpoints, authenticate clients and give them functionality that they bought.

For example:

Client A bought calculator services from you. It authenticates, and makes GET call to /api/calculate/subtract/5/1. You give them response what your calculator does, for example 5-1 = 4. They can use your prepared templates for this data preview or create their own.

Client B bought calculator and storage services from you. You calculate same value, give it back, but also store it in your own database. So client B also can make call GET /api/storage/last_calculation and you give them 4, because client data stored in your database, he bought storage service too so he do not need to setup database for himself.

It is very simple example, but you should get the point.

For example simple scheme with separate database for each client:
[image]

Comment: I don't want sell them my code, I want give them access to my application. So for example they get from me a unique url address. Client A: xxxx.com/client1 Client B: xxxx.com/client2 etc. My app currently is treated as a one project, if you open xxxx.com you have the access to the app, you have one database. I want to make it for many clients with many databases.

Comment: So thats ok, just keep front end client code in your server too. Its same client REST API. If user bought service you let him to get specific source from that service. About databases you can create separate database for each client if there is a lot of tables and a lot of data. Do you really need subdomains? Is it hosting websites services? If not then you don't need separate subdomains. Just authenticate them and give them functionality that they bought. It's hard to say something more specific when you did not wrote what kind if services you will sell.

Comment: Ok, do you mean to make one big database for all clients, keep everything in one project and just give them access to the project? It is some kind of system which helps companies with calendars, employees, statistics. In laravel you have some patterns which you follow, like unique email address in users table. That's why I feel like making separate my app will be better and safer. I just don't know how to make it on the server like Ubuntu. Should I make one big project and ignore laravers patterns or make many applications each for one client and set up domains for them. I need to automate it.

Comment: You should not use any framework pattern. Framework is for easier coding only. You should use patterns according to your business needs. For databases you can create separate for each client if they will be big, but application should be one, it will be harder to maintain multiple of them, you will have some work with file systems, permissions and other things. Later you can scale your application to multiple servers if you will get a lot of clients and will be needing scaling.

Comment: thanks, I think I got the point, I'm going to use dockers and kubernetes.